# SSIS Excel Destination doesn't works

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, dataflow

One SSIS package does the data export from 3 sources to Excel. Before exporting into excel the file, the data goes through sorting, aggregation and finally it goes before Conditional Split. I placed data viewers at every place and could see that the records are there but when the excel is exported i don't see any records.

before the export happens, previous day excel is deleted and a new excel is created from a template excel. At the end of data flow task, I see excel containing columns from template excel and no rows in it.

What is causing this issue. I have kept data viewer and I see the data as it goes by but I don't see data after the conditional split or before the conditional split happens.

Please see the pic. After the conditional split, there are 3 excel destination. One of them which you can see.[image]

Comment: What happens right before the conditional split since you mention that you don't see anything right before that component.

Comment: Is there a problem in the Merge Join? Have you read this article [http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/sorting-in-sql-vs-sorting-in-ssis.html Whenever possible I use a Union All

Comment: @RomilN could you provide more details about the merge join - do you see the correct data for the two inputs of the merge join?

Comment: I couldn't see the data executed after merge join. I have kept data viewer after merge join but the data doesn't show up. I kept the data viewer after Sort task name "Sort 2" and that worked. The package doesn't throw any error but the excel file remains blank

Comment: @MiguelH: can you help??

Comment: @MarkHe: I have added my comments

Comment: @RomilN. I agree with MarkHe, we need more detail on the MergeJoin transformations. I've had problems with these in the past, which is why I tend to use Union All transformations

Comment: As far as the data goes for merge join.. I don't see any issues..but do let me know what info you know exactly need from merge join

Comment: @RomilN so you've enabled data viewer on the two data flows before the merge join and it's correct? What type of join are you performing: `inner`, `left`, etc.

Comment: Yes I have enabled data viewers which doesn't work. I am using inner joins

Comment: @RomilN enable data viewers on each component and work backwards to see where it fails to produce the correct results. From what you're telling me, the two data flows that feed `Merge Join 1` right before the conditional split are already incorrect. So find where the data goes wrong and provide details about that transformation

Comment: @MarkHe: I change join from Inner to Left outer under Merge Join and the data was then exported to excel. But then some of the columns were blank which should have the data. If I change back to Inner join with a purpose to bring the data, then I see blank spreadsheet